# Ignore errors leaving code intact using Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I am attempting to render a Jinja file in a Python script. The file has three types of instructions -

1. typical for loops
2. import instructions
3. run macros from imports

1) All I want are the for loops to be flattened. 
2) In order to get around failing imports, I have subclassed a forgivingLoader. 
3) However I am having issues getting around the imports when it gets invoked. I have tried 2 different ways - subclass unDefined but `{{ abc.callf("arg1", "arg2") }}` gets replaced by `arg1,arg2` since unDefined doesnt have access to the calling function, only the arguments. Alternatively when I use DebugUndefined (which also subclasses unDefined) since the import silently failed it is unable to locate `abc.callf`

Below is an example input and intended output I am targeting. Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Input:

```
Starting  
{% import "abc.yml" as abc %}  
  {{ abc.callf("arg1", "arg2") }}  
{% set forloopvar = ["var1", "var2"] %}  
{% for var in forloopvar %}  
  {{ var }}here  
{% endfor %}  
the end
```

Expected Output:

```
Starting
{% import "abc.yml" as abc %}
  {{ abc.callf("arg1", "arg2") }}
  var1here
  var2here
the end
```